# Javascript: how to ensure that fetch() has finished before using the data?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I'm struggling with `fetch()`, which I'm using to retrieve JSON.  I *think* the problem is that the code completes and tries to 'act' on the array before `fetch()` has actually downloaded and processed it.  I wrote a simpler version initially, which resulted in the same problem; most of the code here [is from Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch).

As shown below (setTimeout only included to demonstrate the problem) I get different results when accessing the same array twice, a second apart:

```
dataResultArray = requestJSONResult(searchString);

console.log(dataResultArray);           // logs '[]'
console.log(dataResultArray.length);    // logs '0'

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(dataResultArray);         // logs the actual JSON array contents
  console.log(dataResultArray.length);  // logs the real array length
}, 1000);


function requestJSONResult(searchString) {
  var tempArray = []

  fetch(`/search/?term=${searchString}`)  
    .then(status)  
    .then(json)  
    .then(function(data) {
      tempArray.push(...data)
    }).catch(function(error) {  
    console.log('Request failed', error);  
    });

  return tempArray;
}

function status(response) {  
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {  
    return Promise.resolve(response)  
  } else {  
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))  
  }  
}

function json(response) {  
  return response.json()  
}
```

Comment: google javascript promises and/or callbacks

Comment: You need to use promises properly.  Return the promise from your function and attach a `then` handler to it, instead of trying to push the result into an array.  There's no way that will work reliably.

Comment: Once you use promises, stick with `then` callbacks, even in your main script that calls these functions. You can only access the asynchronously retrieved data there.

Comment: But... what is the problem? The first `console.log` logs an empty array because the fetch hasn't returned anything yet. The second `console.log` executes after 1 second, and in your case, by that time the fetch has completed. You should just put `console.log` after `tempArray.push`. The timeout is not necessary (and won't work if the fetch takes longer than 1 second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to make your asynchronous code synchronous which is not a good idea.

Just return the promise from fetch to retrieve the data like so:

```js
function requestJSONResult(searchString) {
  return fetch(`/search/?term=${searchString}`)
    .then(status)
    .then(json);
}

function status(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
  }
}

function json(response) {
  return response.json()
}


requestJSONResult(searchString)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.length);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
```

Now your `requestJSONResult` returns a promise that could either resolve or reject so any caller can wait for those events.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that I haven't tested this.  You need to use promises throughout.  Trying to force asynchronous code synchronous is not reliable, as you've discovered.

```
function status(response) {  
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {  
    return Promise.resolve(response)  
  } else {  
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))  
  }  
}
```

Notice line 2 of `requestJSONResult`: `return fetch(....)`.  We return the promise from the function.

```
function requestJSONResult(searchString) {
    return fetch(`/search/?term=${searchString}`)  
        .then(status)  
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })  
        .catch(function(error) {  
            console.log('Request failed', error);  
        });
}

requestJSONResult(searchString)
    .then(function(result) { 
        console.log(result); 
    });
```